# One of my two speakers doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, pavucontrol

I had ubuntu 12.04 alongside with windows and my speakers both worked fine. Now i have only Ubuntu 12.04 in my dasktop installed by a cd, and only one of my speakers work right now. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "sound preferences" from the top right corner of the screen and check if the balance is on the middle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done this. I have tried many things i don't know what else to do. If you have any other idea let me know. Thank you very much.